# SQL repeating rows based on a field value , also increment another field

Tags: sql, repeat, sql-server-2017

I'm stuck and in need of some help please. I am using SQL 2017.

How can I repeat the below data based on field WC_Count but also increase op number as well?

As-is

| Job | StockCode | Warehouse | Op | Op_Count | WC_Count |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 000000000219587 | CODE1 | 1W | 1 | 6 | 4 |
| 000000000219587 | CODE2 | 1W | 2 | 6 | 4 |
| 000000000219587 | CODE3 | 1W | 3 | 6 | 4 |
| 000000000219587 | CODE4 | 1W | 4 | 6 | 4 |
| 000000000219587 | CODE5 | 1W | 5 | 6 | 4 |
| 000000000219587 | CODE6 | 1W | 6 | 6 | 4 |

To be

| Job | StockCode | Warehouse | Op | Op_Count | WC_Count |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 000000000219587 | CODE1 | 1W | 1 | 6 | 4 |
| 000000000219587 | CODE2 | 1W | 2 | 6 | 4 |
| 000000000219587 | CODE3 | 1W | 3 | 6 | 4 |
| 000000000219587 | CODE4 | 1W | 4 | 6 | 4 |
| 000000000219587 | CODE5 | 1W | 5 | 6 | 4 |
| 000000000219587 | CODE6 | 1W | 6 | 6 | 4 |
| 000000000219587 | CODE1 | 1W | 7 | 6 | 4 |
| 000000000219587 | CODE2 | 1W | 8 | 6 | 4 |
| 000000000219587 | CODE3 | 1W | 9 | 6 | 4 |
| 000000000219587 | CODE4 | 1W | 10 | 6 | 4 |
| 000000000219587 | CODE5 | 1W | 11 | 6 | 4 |
| 000000000219587 | CODE6 | 1W | 12 | 6 | 4 |
| 000000000219587 | CODE1 | 1W | 13 | 6 | 4 |
| 000000000219587 | CODE2 | 1W | 14 | 6 | 4 |
| 000000000219587 | CODE3 | 1W | 15 | 6 | 4 |
| 000000000219587 | CODE4 | 1W | 16 | 6 | 4 |
| 000000000219587 | CODE5 | 1W | 17 | 6 | 4 |
| 000000000219587 | CODE6 | 1W | 18 | 6 | 4 |
| 000000000219587 | CODE1 | 1W | 19 | 6 | 4 |
| 000000000219587 | CODE2 | 1W | 20 | 6 | 4 |
| 000000000219587 | CODE3 | 1W | 21 | 6 | 4 |
| 000000000219587 | CODE4 | 1W | 22 | 6 | 4 |
| 000000000219587 | CODE5 | 1W | 23 | 6 | 4 |
| 000000000219587 | CODE6 | 1W | 24 | 6 | 4 |

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.  I am guessing that "SQL 2017" means "SQL Server 2017".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a recursive subquery.  You don't describe the exact logic for incrementing `op`, so I'll just use `row_number()`:

```
with cte as (
      select Job, StockCode, Warehouse, Op, Op_Count, WC_Count, 1 as n
      from t
      union all
      select Job, StockCode, Warehouse, Op, Op_Count, WC_Count, n + 1
      from cte
      where n < wc_count
     )
select Job, StockCode, Warehouse,
       row_number() over (order by n, op) as op,
       op_count, wc_count
from cte;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=fbc7217523116dbcf45c04214285d8dd) is a db<>fiddle.